# Form action an external JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I found a few similar questions, but nothing quite like what I want to do. I want an html form to have the action set to a javascript function from an external file. Here's my attempt.

The html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <form action="javascript:filename.functionname()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function functionname(){
        window.alert('test');
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish in this example is have "test" appear on a JavaScript alert when the submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the onsubmit event.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <form onsubmit="functionname(); return false;">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're right about using onsubmit, but this isn't a quick fix solution. I monkeyed around with other components as well, to no avail of yet.

Comment: Sry, I didn't understand it. No it's not possible to send data from file1.html to file2.html and execute a function in file2.html. 
Maybe you can do it by set the method to GET and read the values in file2.html from the GET Parameter, but I think this is not a good solution.

Comment: There's only one html file and the data should stay there.

Comment: Okay, then I think the onsubmit solution is the best one (and only one (?))

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could define all of this behavior inside of your JavaScript and separate from your form:

The callback function:

```
function processForm(e) {
  //Prevent any form submission
  if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault;
  //Get a reference to the form
  var e = e || window.event;
  var form;
  if(e.target) form = e.target;
  else form = e.srcElement;
  //Do some stuff with the form values here
  // ...
}
```

Triggering the callback (without jQuery):

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
if(form.attachEvent) {
  form.attachEvent('submit', processForm);
} else {
  form.addEventListener('submit', processForm);
}
```

Triggering the callback (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myForm').submit(processForm);
});
```

All of the code (the jQuery method or the non-jQuery method) could be contained within a single JavaScript file that you include in your HTML `<head>`.